# How to create a CouchDB View to join documents based on multiple, non-unique fields

Tags: couchdb

I have a database with documents in the following forms:

{"Type" : "A", "Date": "2013-09-19", "Week" : "A", "Day" : "Mon"}

{"Type" : "B", "Week" : "A", "Day" : "Mon", "Class" : "xyz"}

How do I create a view that will list all the classes (from doc.Type = "B") for a specific date (from doc.Type = "A")? Essentially it means matching the "Week" and "Day" fields. I have found examples (mostly based on Christopher Lenz's solution) but these are matching based on just one field being matched, which is unique in one of the document types.

### Update

To clarify in response to @Daniel:

I would like be able to input a date into the URL query. This will match a type "A" doc. From this, I want all the type B docs that have the same Week and Day values as the original type A.

Comment: Could you use the technique of CouchDb joins (covered before on SO) discussed in this post: http://www.cmlenz.net/archives/2007/10/couchdb-joins

Comment: @Daniel I have looked at that article. Restructuring the data is not an option for me and his solution at the bottom is the same as Lenz's solution - which I can't seem to make work for my situation: the key for doc.Type = "A" would be Date, but for doc.Type = "B" it is Week and Day and my brain can't figure out a startkey and endkey pattern that will return the docs in the desired order (not to say that it isn't necessarily possible with this method, I just can't see it yet!).

Comment: Is the search made against [Week, Day] or Date? If the first wouldn't the [Week, Day, 0] for Type A and [Week, Day, 1] for Type B work, where the query is made using startkey and endkey and perhaps outputting Class for B? https://gist.github.com/danielwertheim/6638412

Comment: @Daniel OK that was actually Lenz's site - but I have seen it crop in quite a few other places as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading this, I don't see how it can be done in Couch with *just one* query (you can only query one view at a time) since doc type B has no `date` field. No `date` in doc type B makes a single view with a compound key impossible. You could do it pretty easy in *two* queries with no doc changes/restructuring needed.

First query, by `date` on a type A view will give you the `day` and `week` values you need for second query.

Second query would run against a view with a compound key something like this...

```
"views": {
    "type-A-by-date": {
        "map": "function(doc) { 
            if (doc.type && (doc.type == 'A') { 
                emit([doc.date], [doc.week,doc.day]); 
            } 
        }"
   },
    "type-B-by-week-day": {
        "map": "function(doc) { 
            if (doc.type && doc.type == 'B') { 
                emit([doc.week,doc.day], doc); 
            } 
        }"
   },
```

Now you will have your type B docs that have `week` and `day` that match that original `date` query.

LMK if you need any more info :-)